# Problems hiding scrollbars in QWebView

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to hide the scrollbars on a QWebView have tried this:

webView.page()->mainFrame()->setScrollBarPolicy( Qt::Vertical, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff );
webView.page()->mainFrame()->setScrollBarPolicy( Qt::Horizontal, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff );

but Qt is giving me this error:

"invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QWebFrame' forward declaration of 'struct QWebFrame'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such an error message in Qt usually means that you have to `#include <QWebFrame>`.